# Avoid recursive cache in PHP / HTML

Tags: php, html, caching, resources

I'm using the next code in order to prevent cache:

```
<?php

  header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT");
  header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");

?>
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
      <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
      <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
      <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

But I have a doubt about it, does it work ONLY for the current page, or it does for all the page resources? If not, what could be the best approach for avoid recursive caching? Thank's!

Comment: only 'works' for the page the code is in. you can configure the server, to do this to cover all pages.

Comment: I'm using Apache, how can I do that with an htaccess? (let me google a bit and then I'll be back lol)